# Habilitar 'Duración de Sesión' en AppCenter de Microsoft

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin

Estoy implementando unas métricas para una app con `Ms AppCenter`, seguí la documentación y funciona todo muy bien con excepción de la `duración de sesión` (`session duration`).

La documentación dice que basta con agregar esta linea para iniciar el seguimiento (La agregue en `OnCreate()` ), pero no me muestra nada en la sección 'duración de sesión':

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("Nombre del Evento - Evento #5");
```

**Me hace falta algo extra?**

Adjunto captura del panel mostrando los resultados de la app de prueba
(Muestra los demás resultados de forma correcta: Usuarios activos, Logs, etc.)

[image: error]

[image: error2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tomar en cuenta que el registro de los eventos no es automatico y debes espera un poco pero ademas es importante definir un id

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("UserId", "id usuario");
//Analytics.trackEvent("Nombre del Evento - Evento #5", properties);
Analytics.TrackEvent("Nombre del Evento - Evento #5");
```

Debes considerar tambièn:

Si no se identifican eventos personalizados dentro de los 5 minutos de una sesión, la sesión no se contará.

Comment: Gracias Jorsesys, pero entonces si estoy declarando correctamente el evento con la linea de codigo que comparti? No necesita nada mas?

Comment: Solo eso, hay que esperar un poco.